# Java OutOfMemoryError caused by multiple event tiggers?

Tags: java

Suppose a function in a thread gets called on a specific event, and assume that the function has a runtime of 1 sec and suppose that this event happens 5 times a second, could that lead to Java OutOfMemory Errors?

Basically it is one thread that is open and its role is to listen to messages. Each message that comes in will trigger an event. My question, is what happens if this thread receives more messages that it could handle? would that build an event queue that would create an OutOfMemory Exception? or would the messages be ignored?

Update:
it must have been a network queue, or some socket issue, messages were received over the network and the result of the processing, after the event was triggered, was written back on the network. When I removed the write back on the network, after the processing, the issue was solved.

Comment: So, you're asking if starting 5 threads can cause you to run out of memory?

Comment: I imagine if it tries to allocate memory and there isn't enough available, no matter what the circumstances, then you will get this error

Comment: I have no idea, what happens if the messages are received and the thread is busy processing older messages. Again, assume that the thread needs 1 sec to run and you receive 5 messages per sec.

Comment: It depends; different queues have different limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what exactly you mean by "Listen to event 5 times a second" and the implementation.
Examples:

Java Swing EDT and clicking 5 times a second:
Will NOT receive new GUI events wherever they come from. While the EDT is busy the GUI is locked.

Java NIO Socket Selector thread:
Selector will process messages as they come in, at some point they will overflow the socket buffer and the connection will get terminated (or become very slow if the OS notices it is still being read sometimes)

Java Scheduling Executor invoking runnable 5 times a second:
Your runnable will not be scheduled until the previous one is done. The other messages are ignored.

My own custom event handling thread that puts them in a heap-based queue:
Will eat up heap until it either runs out of memory or reaches maximum size (at which point probably fails anyway)

Comment: "Java Scheduling Executor invoking runnable 5 times a second:
Your runnable will not be scheduled until the previous one is done. The other messages are ignored." 

**will the message be ignored or put in a queue?**

Comment: @user3564557 If it is one runnable being executed - there will not even be a message, the scheduler will simply not make an event until the previous is done. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111402/threadpooltaskscheduler-behaviour-when-pool-is-full/23113328#23113328

Answer (score 0):

If you have some kind of Event-Loop, there will be an Event-Queue.

If you create more events, than you can handle, there are at least two possibilities:

1. All Messages will be stored in that queue and if no more memory can be allocated, there will be the OutOfMemoryError
2. The Queue may also throw an Exception, if a new Event should be created.

In both cases, you application will stop to work.